# Tilted mobile accelerometer android

Tags: android, math, accelerometer

I'm trying to make a little game in which you have to move some object tilting the mobile phone. I achieved this following this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/228656/Tilt-Ball-Walkthrough

The case is this is based on the mobile being in a 0 degrees as origin but I would like to change the origin angle to one more comfortable: an angle aiming my face as origin.

How can I normalize the acceleration variables x, y given by the accelerometer to my natural angle (aiming my face)?

Comment: I've been thinking of doing something similar, but I haven't tried it yet. My first step will be to try to grab the initial orientation somewhere after the accelerometer has been initialized, like `onStart()`, and use that as a first estimate of "zero".

Comment: Well, you better be careful with that. You don't know if at that moment the mobile is landed or whatever. I think we should find a comfortable angle and work with that. The player will get used to it... but how can we do this?

Comment: That's the difficulty, isn't it. You don't know if the user started the app with the device flat on the table and then picked it up. For my uses, I plan to have the "zero" orientation slowly change to the current orientation. If the orientation stays stable for long enough, current and zero will be equal. But my application is highly tolerant of error. For a game I would just use the orientation when the user presses a `Start` button. We probably need to know more about your application for more cogent suggestions.

Comment: But what I'm looking for is how to find the angle of the device in a specific moment and how to converse the acceleration variables with that.

Comment: Are you asking how to subtract the initial vectors from the current vectors?

Comment: I don't know how to change the origin from the acceleration variables because they are being taken supposing the device is in an horizontal position. I want that with a given angle, converse this variables with it.

Comment: accelerometer android example http://www.quicktips.in/get-accelerometer-readings-android/